# What is the difference between theses two methods in roleprovider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

As I was going through implementing a custom role provider I came across these two methods

```
public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName) {}
public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch) {}
```

Aren't these the same thing? You provide a role and get all the users that are in that role back? Actually I don't even get what the point of the usernameToMatch in the FindUsersInRole is for... My understanding is that is should return multiple users, but wouldn't this limit it to one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember right `GetUsersInRole` will get all the users that have that role. This is the `aspnetdb` sql query it executes :

```
SELECT u.UserName
FROM   dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles ur
WHERE  u.UserId = ur.UserId AND @RoleId = ur.RoleId AND u.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId
ORDER BY u.UserName
```

In `FindUsersInRole`, you send over a rolename as well as a username pattern.  The method will return a user that match the username.  Here is the `aspnetdb` sql for this method :

```
SELECT u.UserName
FROM   dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles ur
WHERE  u.UserId = ur.UserId AND @RoleId = ur.RoleId AND u.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId AND LoweredUserName LIKE LOWER(@UserNameToMatch)
ORDER BY u.UserName
```

So the two methods serve two different functions.

Comment: So the FindUsersInRole should only return one user? Maybe it's me but the method name and return type imply that a list of users gets returned.

Comment: FindUsersInRole allows filtering, like 'si%', to only return users starting with 'si'.

Comment: Good observation - the LIKE in the sql statement can take anything such as si% as Simon said or even a wilder match like %si%.  I personally would not send in a string like that and you are right, without looking at the sql statement who would know you could do that.